# How should we type controls in formBuilder?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

How should we type controls in formBuilder - I was looking for an answer and there is no answer so far, the problem is this

we create an interface:

```
interface myForm {
  name: string;
  age: number | null;
}
```

and create a form:

```
userForm = this.fb.group<myForm>({
  name: '',
  age: null
})
```

and now when I want to update the name I don't get any errors:

```
userForm.get('name').setValue(200);
```

So is there any way to also type forms that are built using formBuilder? Do we have to write an unnecessary boilerplate

Comment: your interface definition is wrong: 

interface myForm {
  name: string;
  age: number | null;
}

Comment: It doesn't change anything i just wrote code on my lap ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways (also yours) for `TypedForms`.

```js
userForm = this.fb.group({
  name: this.fb.control<string>(''),
  age: this.fb.control<boolean>(null),
});
// or
userForm = this.fb.group<myForm>({
  name: '',
  age: null
});


// wont work
userForm.controls.name.setValue(200);

// also wont work
userForm.patchValue({ name: 200 });

// this work because, this access is not typesafe
userForm.get('name').setValue(200);
```

Special note: If you set the type of `userForm` to `UntypedForm`, than it is not typesafe again. Your setup should be look more like this:

```js
export class YourComponet {

   public userForm = this.fb.group(...);

   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
   }
}
```